# In Aura component how can I display the account name as lookup field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

In Aura component how can I display the account as lookup field? In desktop below code successfully display the client lookup but in mobile it display only ID

```
A lookup to Account
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="MyObject__c">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.MyModel.cReport.Account__c}"  />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a custom lookup component.

> The lookup type is supported in the Lightning Experience only. When used
>   in the mobile app, the lookup type is rendered as an input text field.
>   Dependent lookups are not supported.

[Read Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)

Reference for custom component

https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

Conditional Rendering For Phone 
Use [**$Browser**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm)

> The $Browser global value provider returns information about the
>   hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the
>   application.

There is various Attribute available on `$Browser` i.e `{!$Browser.isPhone}` returns true or false based on a browser is running on phone or not

Example

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isPhone}">
    Use field to display for mobile
    <aura:set attribute="else">
     Use field to display for Desktop
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: how can I change the output to display name only in mobile and lookup in desktop

Comment: @MaheshIndia I update my answer for conditional rendering in mobile